# JavaScript on window load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to set the script below to start on page load so that if the company name has been entered the vat field will automatically show up, could any one give me a hand on this?

```
//--></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('.colorbox').colorbox({
    width: 560,
    height: 560
});
$("input[name=company]").blur(function() {
  if($(this).val().length>0) {
    $("#vat").show();
    $("#fiscal").hide();
    $("#vat").find("input").eq(0).focus();
  } else {
    $("#vat").hide();
    $("#fiscal").show();
    $("#fiscal").find("input").eq(0).focus();
  }
});

//--></script>
```

Comment: Lesson 1: Java is not JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
$(function() {
    showvat($("input[name=company]"));
    $("input[name=company]").blur(function() {
        showvat($(this));
    });
});

function showvat(element) {
    if(element.val().length>0) {
        $("#vat").show(); 
        $("#fiscal").hide();
        $("#vat").find("input").eq(0).focus();
    } else {
        $("#vat").hide();
        $("#fiscal").show();
        $("#fiscal").find("input").eq(0).focus();
    }
}
```

**Note That:**

`$(function() {..});` is the same as `$(document).ready(function() {});`

**You can also attach the function to `$(window).load(function(){})`;**

- [$(document).ready(function() {..})](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)
- [$(window).load(function(){..}](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Comment: might be worth pointing out that `$(function() { //...` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){ //...`.  I prefer the more verbose version, but thats just me ;-)

Comment: Thank YOU!!!!!!!! Nandakumar V this worked like a charm!!!!!!
and thank you Zach L for the extra info

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of this working: http://jsfiddle.net/fPtJ8/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // original code here
});
```

​Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you Cymen 
this would have come handy i will try it out

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using JQuery, I'd probably use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // your code...
});
```

or

```
$(window).load(function(){
   // your code...
});
```

The former runs your code after the `DOM` is "ready" for manipulation. The latter runs your code after all of the page elements have loaded (images, etc...)

Check this SO post for more info: [window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)